# Loading Content Via Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

Ok, so I'm pretty new to ajax and loading content externally and would appreciate any insight to my problem.

I currently have a hidden div that is empty where the ajax content should load in after a link is clicked.

```
<div id="#ajax-wrap"></div>
```

I currently have a list of links that all have the same class and I'd like to have, when clicked, the blank div do a slide toggle and then load in the content from the page that the link was to.

Link:

```
<a href="always a different url" class="home-right"></a>
```

Current jQuery:

```
$("a.home-right").click(function () {
$('#ajax-wrap').slideToggle();
});
```

Being as I'm new to Ajax and loading the external content, I'd like to know how to load content from the linked page that's house in the `#content` tag.  So essentially, I'd like a `.home-right` link, `#ajax-wrap` would slide toggle, and then Ajax would pull content from the linked page (which is always going to be a different random link) and it's `#content` div, placing that content in `#ajax-wrap`.

Thanks in advance for any help folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the `ajax` for the links. Requirements:

1. Writing a handler for links.
2. We must cancel the default behaviour of browser when somebody click on a link (that redirect to the page).
3. Removing old data ajax recieved from server and make the `#ajax-wrap` fresh.
4. Load the remote page via ajax and set it to `#ajax-wrap`.
5. Now slide it down.

---

```
// Document Ready
$(function () {

    // attaching click handler to links
    $("a.home-right").click(function (e) {
        // cancel the default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();

        // get the address of the link
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // getting the desired element for working with it later
        var $wrap = $('#ajax-wrap');

        $wrap
            // removing old data
            .html('')

            // slide it up
            .slideUp()

            // load the remote page
            .load(href + ' #content', function () {
                // now slide it down
                $wrap.slideDown();
            });
    });

});
```

Comment: You rock!  This is precisely what I needed.  Thank you very much.

Comment: would there be a way to a have a close button once the content is shown?  For instance, if I wanted  to make the element #close-button able to close the content that has been slide down, how would I incorporate that into this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `ajax` like this:

```
$("a.home-right").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "YOUR URL HERE",
    success: function(data){
           $('#ajax-wrap').html(data);
          $('#ajax-wrap').slideToggle();
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("An error occured");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You're not setting the HTML into `#ajax-wrap`?

Comment: Pardon me but what do you mean by setting the HTML into `#ajax-wrap`?

Comment: he means putting `#content` from the ajax response into `#ajax-wrap`

Comment: `#content` is it placed inside the `#ajax-wrap`?
e.g. `<div id="#ajax-wrap">
         <div id="content"></div>
     </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
// Inside click handler
$.get('url_that_returns_data')
  .done(function(response){
    var $response = $(response);
    $('#ajax-wrap').html($response.find('#content')).slideToggle();
  });
```

Comment: i think you mean `$('#ajax-wrap').load('the_url_that_returns_data #content').slideToggle()`

Comment: ah ok, I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.home-right").click(function () {
          $('#ajax-wrap').slideUp();                                  
           var url = $(this).attr("href")                                 
          $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: url,
            success: function(msg){
                $('#ajax-wrap').html(msg)        
                $('#ajax-wrap').slideDown();
            },
            error: function(){
              alert("An error occured");
            }
      });
    })

})
```