# How can I filter / query wordpress posts using ajax, live?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, filter

I have a Wordpress website, that has a number of posts, and a number of filters (with only the UI set up) in a theme that is a custom build.

Want I want to  to do is change the query posts tags live using AJAX, so that the user can get the posts they want using the filters:

- Popularity (custom taxonomy)
- Time posted
- Tags
- Colour (custom),
- Keyword (using a search bar)
- Category

I have found a php script that does a similar thing, but not live, and does not give the ability to update live; this script is here that does the query.

```
<?php if( !empty($_GET['order']) ) $order=$_GET['order'];
else $order='DESC'; // default

if( !empty($_GET['orderby']) ) $orderby=$_GET['orderby'];
else $orderby = 'Date'; // default
if( !empty($_GET['cat']) ) $orderby=$_GET['cat'];
else $category = ''; // default


query_posts('orderby='.$orderby.'&order='.$order.'&meta_key='.'_post_like_count'.'&cat='.$category)
            ?>
```

The script that does the changing (that changes the queries) is here, effectively an anchor that adds a url onto the the search term.

```
<a href="?order=DESC&orderby=meta_value_num">Popular</a>
```

I have only done the querying for a few values, before I get the whole filtering system working, and I acknowledge that it may have to be completely re done, as I know that ajax cannot change the url live for the user, and has to use requests.

**Does anyone know how I could approach this task in any way, and can someone give me some guidance on how to achieve it?**

I am open to plugins, yet I would prefer integrating it locally into my custom theme build.

Comment: It is very easy indeed, why don't you check [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601139/loading-content-via-ajax#answer-16601272)?

Comment: That has nothing to do with filtering, only ajax calls.

Comment: I understood you already created the page with filtering, so just use ajax to pull the content. You know how to filter posts, you know how to pull the content using ajax, so what is the problem?